# I need the template created by SharpDX Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharpdx

This extension is broken for me. I already contacted the developer and the bug will be fixed upon it's next release. In the meantime, I'd really like to start learning DirectX (but I want to keep a safe distance from C++). Could anyone be so kind as to copy and paste the template the extension creates in it's whole? And also give me a list of the references it adds to the project. Thanks a lot. Sorry if the question is not well written, but I'm very ill at the moment. Thanks for any cooperation.

Comment: Take any of the samples located in 'Samples\Toolkit\' and use it as base for your project. If you will move the project to a different folder - open the csproj file with any text editor and correct the path to the "SharpDX.targets" file (included at the end of csproj).

Comment: Thanks, that is probably going to work. I was looking at the samples' codes and running them, they look a lot like XNA. I thought SharpDX would be similar to OpenGL wrapping libraries where each function has a corresponding method call that you make from a static class. So studying DirectX will lead me nowhere in learning SharpDX...

Comment: Actually SharpDX **is** a wrapper. I saw just the `Toolkit` portion which looks like XNA, however the low-level DirectX API is fully accessible and it is nearly 1-to-1 mapping to C++ DirectX methods - they are just grouped in classes and named following C# coding rules. Toolkit is fully integrated with all this - have a look at the classes and you will see that they have defined cast operators to the corresponding low-level objects.